# Trying to use Set-PnPList -Identity "TestLib" -DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary "Restricted" to set sensitivity label to SharePoint Document Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I have a requirement to add sensitivity label to document libraries of multiple site collections.

I found below PnP PowerShell Command as per https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPList.html

Set-PnPList -Identity "Demo List" -DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary "Confidential" -Connection $ModernSiteConnection

$ModernSiteConnection = Connection establish using certificate and working for other operations like applying sensitivity label to site collection.so no issue with connection

but the above command for applying sensitivity Label for Document library is not working saying A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary'
even i can not see DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary in intelligence while other all parameter i can see and tried one of those like EnableContentTypes it worked.

I am using 2.2.1 version of pnp.powershell

can you please help me to understand what is the problem.

Trying to add sensitivity label to document library using pnp powershell
Set-PnPList -Identity  $LibraryName -DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary "Restricted" -Connection $ModernSiteConnection

but getting error A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary'

Comment: Can you confirm the PnP PowerShell version once again? I think stable & latest PnP PowerShell is `2.2.0`. `DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary` parameter was added to PnP PowerShell in `v2.1.0`. Try uninstalling all PnP PowerShell modules from your system and install it again by following the steps given here: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap-MVP  for giving me the direction to check it again, what i found that i have both SharePointPnPPowershellOnline and PnP.Powershell and Set-PnPList was coming from SharePointPnPPowershellOnline. so i uninstalled it and PnP Powershell all versions and installed stable version of PnP Powershell. And now when i am trying to Set-PnPList  -identity "LibraryName" -DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary "Restricted"  it is saying to pass access token.  do we have a proper documentation for DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary, like how to pass access token in this command(Set PnPList)

Comment: Check [this](https://office365itpros.com/2022/01/28/default-sensitivity-label-doclib/) and [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/recursively-apply-sensitivity-label-spo-document-library-merilles). Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some version conflict in the PnP PowerShell modules/versions installed on your system.

I think the current stable & latest of PnP PowerShell is `v2.2.0`.

And `DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary` parameter of `Set-PnPList` cmdlet was added to PnP PowerShell in `v2.1.0`.

Try below steps once:

1. Uninstall all versions of `SharePointPnPPowershellOnline` module from your system.
2. Uninstall all versions of PnP PowerShell modules from your system
3. Install the latest and stable version (`v2.2.0`) of PnP PowerShell by following below documentations

**Documentations**:

1. [Upgrading from the Legacy version of PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/upgrading.html)
2. [Installing PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)